# How to start progress bar count down at the beginning of longPressGesture?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I need a way or a delegate to start a progress bar count down when user touch (Long press ) a table view cell.
The problem is i can't find the delegate of start recognise a gesture.

Comment: See `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: UILongPressGestureRecognizer only can be triggered after the long press happened. I need show progress bar to indicate the long press is happening until time is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the table view delegate method tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath: or tableView:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:. Both of these methods are called when you touch down on a row. You can use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to tell when the user has lifted their finger.